# Do I need to encode attribute values in MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, html-encode

In a cshtml file, I'm assigning a string to an attribute.  For example:

```
<input name="somename" value="@Model.Value">
```

Since @Model.Value string could contain any Unicode character, obviously the string must be encoded.  Will Razor encode this value automatically?  I'm guessing it won't or can't because I could easily put a @Html.Raw immediately after it to break up the whole thing into two tags.

I think what I need to do is this:

```
<input name="somename" value="@Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Value))">
```

Is that correct?

Likewise, if I'm embedding an string value in a JavaScript string in a script, should I use:

```
//I could use Ajax instead of HttpUtility here, but Ajax just wraps the same call.
<script>$('id').data('key','@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Value))');</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Razor performs HTML encoding on strings by default.  Depending on where your string is being injected into the HTML stream, this may or may not be the correct encoding to use.   If it's not the correct encoding, then you need to perform the correct encoding yourself and be sure to return an MvcHtmlString (i.e. an IHtmlString) to ensure Razor leaves your custom encoding alone.

Since Razor uses HTML encoding, which is technically different from HTML attribute encoding (it's a subset), it's not wrong to use @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Value)) to HTML attribute encode the value.  At the same time, it's also not necessary, since the default HTML encoding uses the same basic format and will just end up encoding a couple character that otherwise wouldn't need encoded in an HTML attribute value.

On the other hand, in the final case where a string is being injected into the quotes of a JavaScript string, the HTML encoding would absolutely be incorrect, so you'd definitely need to perform the encoding yourself as I did: @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Value)).

Answer (score 0):

Razor automatically encodes it, so you dont need to.

To be specific it is Encoded using HttpUtility Encode / Decode methods and this happens to anything that is not an [IHtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihtmlstring.aspx) such as MvcHtmlString.

Encoding it again would be redundant. If you need to escape this behavor, you need to use the Html.Raw helper, which can be a security risk if the user inputs the model value you are rendering.

Comment: Calling @Html.Raw(Html.AttributeEncode(Model.Value)) is not redundant, since Razor encodes the final value only if it's of type string. Since I'm encoding it and returning an MvcHtmlString, Razor won't try to encode it again. *HTML attribute encoding* only encodes a subset of the characters that *HTML encoding* does, but since the encoding uses the same format (e.g. "&name;", "&#nnnn;") and it's okay to encode characters that wouldn't otherwise need encoding, the HTML encoding Razor does is sufficient for both HTML and HTML attribute values. So it's safe to just use @Model.Value in this case.

Comment: I'm also well-aware of the need for encoding to avoid security risks like HTML-injection.  I was just pointing out that unless Razor is smart enough to know the context of where the string is being embedded, it couldn't possibly choose a different encoding for HTML attribute values vs HTML content.  It doesn't, and because attribute encoding is a subset of HTML encoding, it's fine to just HTML encode everything regardless of where the Razor string ends up.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13246856/88409

Comment: I should also mention that in the case of the @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.Value)), that is absolutely necessary, because HTML encoding would be wrong and could actually lead to a security risk.  In that case, you absolutely have to take control of the encoding and ensure that what you're injecting into the HTML stream at the precise location you're injecting it is correctly formatted.