# How to disable a Stored cross site scripting in code which saying by checkmarx analysis tool?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, encode, checkmarx, secure-coding

I got below security vulnerability from *Checkmarx*.

> `AlcoholTrackerWebApp/AlcoholTrackerWebApp/Controllers/HomeController.cs` gets data from the database,
> for the `ToList` element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly filtered or
> encoded and is eventually displayed to the user in method `SubmitEventRequest` at **line 20** of
> `AlcoholTrackerWebApp/AlcoholTrackerWebApp/Controllers/HomeController.cs`. This may enable a Stored
> **Cross-Site-Scripting** attack.

```cs
public ActionResult SubmitEventRequest()
{
    AlcoholTrackerContext db = new AlcoholTrackerContext();
    string winlogin = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
             
    var intname = winlogin.Substring(winlogin.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
    ViewBag.IDSID = intname;
    var name = db.WorkerInfoes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IDSID.Equals(intname));
    ViewBag.name = name.FirstName + " " + name.LastName;
    ViewBag.WWID = name.OrgUnitDescr;
    ViewBag.ConsumptionMethod = db.AlcoholConsumptions;
    ViewBag.ConsumptionMethod = new SelectList(db.AlcoholConsumptions, "AlcoholConsumptionId", "ConsumptionMethod");
             
    return View(new Event());
}
```

If I do below with using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` then there is no security vulnerability found in the *Checkmarx* tool.

```cs
ViewBag.ConsumptionMethod =
    new SelectList(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(db.AlcoholConsumptions), "AlcoholConsumptionId", "ConsumptionMethod");
```

But with the above fix, I am getting an error in *Razor View* for Dropdown:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AlcoholConsumptionId,
    ViewBag.ConsumptionMethod as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,
    "---Please Select---",
    new {
            id = "AlcoholConsumptionMethod",
            @class = "form-control-new",
            style = "margin-left:-788px;margin-top:20px;width:20.5%"
        }
)
```

> Error in View: DataBinding: 'System.Char' does not contain a property with the name 'AlcoholConsumptionId'.

Answer (score 2):

`db.AlcoholConsumptions` is of type `IEnumerable`, and HTML encoding an `IEnumerable` would not produce the result you are expecting nor it will return an `IEnumerable` that SelectList accepts

using *Razor Views* [automatically encodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31349297/do-i-need-to-encode-attribute-values-in-mvc-razor) data though, (*unless you use `Html.Raw`*) so you can remove the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` but *Checkmarx* will see that you're not explicitly making a call so you'd get the XSS back.

HTML encode `AlcoholConsumptionId` before adding it into `db.AlcoholConsumptions` .