# Encode javascript tags in HTML string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a HTML string that can contain script tags as this:

```
<td class="datagrid-cell" style="text-align:center;" i18n="  
 <script>alert(1);</script>">
</td>
```

and when in my jQuery script I set the HTML in the container with

```
$(target).html(html);
```

and display the container, the script is execupted.
How can I encode the script so that is displayed as text?

Thanks

Comment: See this question as it is the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246540/html-and-attribute-encoding

Comment: HTML encode the `i18n` attribute value. This should be done at the point you set the value, not in the jQuery. If you can show us the code generating the `td`, then we can show you how to do this